# Why do I get a "closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure" here?

Tags: rust

I have a generic `Interface` trait. `Interface` has a `method`, which will be called using dynamic dispatch. Specifically, I'll be passing around `Rc<RefCell<dyn Interface>>`.

I have a use case where I need to wrap a call to `method` inside a closure. The desired behavior is that calling the closure with `input` would be identical to calling `obj.method` with `input` where `obj` implements `Interface`.

The following is my attempt so far.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

pub trait Interface<'p, T> {
    fn method<'s: 'p>(&'p self, input: &'s str) -> T;
}

fn wrap_interface_with_closure<'p, 's: 'p, T: 'p>(
    instance: Rc<RefCell<dyn Interface<'p, T>>>,
) -> impl FnMut(&'s str) -> T + 'p {
    move |input| (*instance).borrow().method(input)
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed
   |
13 |     instance: Rc<RefCell<dyn Interface<'p, T>>>,
   |     -------- lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `instance`
14 | ) -> impl FnMut(&'s str) -> T + 'p {
15 |     move |input| (*instance).borrow().method(input)
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------
   |                  |                                |
   |                  |                                temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
   |                  creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
   |                  argument requires that borrow lasts for `'2`

error: lifetime may not live long enough
   |
13 |     instance: Rc<RefCell<dyn Interface<'p, T>>>,
   |     -------- lifetime `'2` appears in the type of `instance`
14 | ) -> impl FnMut(&'s str) -> T + 'p {
15 |     move |input| (*instance).borrow().method(input)
   |     ------------   ^^^^^^^^ closure capture requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |     |
   |     lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
   |
   = note: closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 2 warnings emitted
```

When it says `closure implements FnMut, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure` which captured variable is it talking about? Is it saying that `instance` is escaping? Does it mean that the borrow is escaping?

Comment: Do we really need lifetimes here? I experimentally removed them and everything compiled fine. [PlaygroundLink](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=11ec046c92aef46aac2d648bb6e7f116)

Comment: You're absolutely right. Adding explicit lifetime annotations here breaks everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trait requires `&'p self`, i.e. the reference to `self` must be the same as `'p`. Inside your closure you call `borrow()`:

```rust
(*instance).borrow()
```

You obtain a reference to the Interface, whose lifetime lasts only throughout the closure (`'1`). However, your trait definition requires that the lifetime of `self` be `'p`:

```rust
fn method<'s: 'p>(&'p self, input: &'s str) -> T;
```

So, when you call `.method()` in your closure, the lifetime of `self` will be  `'1` (valid inside the closure), which doesn't live long enough to satisfy the lifetime `'p` from your parameter. You can fix this by removing the requirement for self:

```rust
fn method<'s: 'p>(&self, input: &'s str) -> T;
```

You can still be sure that `input` outlives your `instance`, since `'s :'p` is part of your `wrap_interface_with_closure` function.